# Bash compare two strings with backslash in string

Tags: string, bash, compare, backslash

This isn't my exact issue but for simplicity purposes, here we go.

If I run the following I need this to return a files match but for some reason in my string if it contains a backslash it will always fail.

The file testmonitor.txt contains only the following text

hello\ world

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$(cat /tmp/testmonitor.txt)
if [[ $file == $file ]]; then  
     echo "files match"   
else  
    echo "files not matching"  
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Unquoted, the right-hand side is treated as a pattern, and the *pattern* `hello\ world` is equivalent to the pattern `hello world`, which does not match the literal text `hello\ world`.

Quote the right-hand side to ensure you perform an exact string comparison instead of pattern matching.

```
if [[ $file == "$file" ]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually set variables in double quotes resolve such problems

```
if [[ "$file" == "$file" ]]; then
```