# Comparing two string variables in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement

This block of code keeps echoing "they are equal" Why?

```
#!/bin/bash

foo="hello"
bar="h"
if [[ "$foo"=="$bar" ]]; then
        echo "they are equal"
else
        echo "they are not equal"
fi
```

Comment: the operators will always need spaces around them, but also note fwiw that the `[[...]]` works differently than the `[...]` ; one difference is that you actually don't need the quotes (`"..."`) with the double `[[...]]` see 
 https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html and  https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/testconstructs.html#DBLBRACKETS

Comment: @michael That's not entirely true; if the string on the right side of a `[[ == ]]` test isn't quoted, it's treated as a glob (wildcard) pattern, which can cause [weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002801) [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656293). IMO it's much easier and safer to just always double-quote variable references (unless there's a specific reason not to, like if you *want* it treated as a glob pattern) than it is to try to remember all the weird exception cases like this.

Comment: @GordonDavisson very true, I always quote as well, better safe than sorry. Main point being that `[[...]]` is different than `[...]`, and I should have just mentioned eg the differing operators available, but also quoting has "different" rules.

Comment: ps: for those following along, here's the exact issue when NOT using quotes: `bar="hello"; foo="h*"; [[ $bar == $foo ]] && echo equal  || echo nope` prints "equal", for better or worse, but `[[ "$bar" == "$foo" ]] && echo equal  || echo nope` prints `nope`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition works based on the number of elements within it, and this particular issue is covered by this (paraphrased) part of the man-page:

> `string`: True if the length of string is non-zero.
>
> `string1 == string2`: True  if  the strings are equal.

In other words, a comparison needs *three* elements, meaning you need a space on either side of the `==`.

Without that it's simply the one-element variant of the condition, which is true when the string is non-empty, as `hello==h` most definitely is.